# Trying to test sending of email in rSpec but ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty? is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

I have no idea why it's not working. After hours of trying to figure this out I wrote a small test to check if the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries was empty and it was.

When I test my reset form it works and mail is sent but when I run test it doesn't seem to store anything in the array.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Passwords" do
  describe "reset password" do
    it "emails user when requesting password reset" do

        visit login_path
        click_link "Forgot Password?"
        response.should render_template "passwords/new"
        response.should have_selector :h1, :content => "Reset Password"
        fill_in "password_reset[email]", :with => "foobar@gmail.com"

        click_button "Reset Password"

        response.should render_template "users/new"
        response.should have_selector :div, :id => "flash_notice", :content => "Email sent with password reset instructions."


         ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?.should be_true
 #       mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last


    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In my `spec_helper.rb` file, I've had to explicitly set `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` before; have you tried this?

Comment: Where about in the spec_helper file did you add this? I just tried adding it to the RSpec.configure do |config| block and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: I put it outside of the `config` block. I remember having lots of issues, I'm not 100% sure that's what fixed it.

Comment: no luck, i've been at it for hours now. The form works and everything but would like my testing to work

Comment: So, shouldn't your test read `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?.should be_false` to conform to your code?

Comment: I was checking to see if the array was empty to confirm that the message wasn't being delivered to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always seem to do silly things like this:

Because I created the passwords_spec file manually and not using the rspec generator I forgot to add "require 'spec_helper'" at the top of the file. Something that the generator would have done automatically.

The last few days I have been figuring out my silly mistakes. Funny how all this happened when I got lazy and decided to build my app first then test after. Well I've learnt from my mistake. Test first!

Answer (score 2):

Just found out a great gem to test emails with rspec: https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec

Hope it will help.